# Viscosity Question

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

If the fluid has zero viscosity, does that mean it is at rest? Would it be possible that the fluid is both at rest and has zero viscosity? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Viscosity is the description of a fluid's resistance to deformation. Often we discuss inviscid flows as a means of simplifying problems so to answer your question an inviscid can indeed be moving. The fact it is inviscid does not suggest it is at rest, only that it has no resistance to shear stress.

Take a look at ideal fluid flows for example.